# Finding the Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have encountered the following question:

**Question**: Consider the Laurent expansion

$$ \dfrac{e^{z}}{\cos(2z)} = \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}, \qquad \dfrac{\pi}{4} < \vert z \vert < \dfrac{3\pi}{4}. $$

Determine the coefficients $a_{-1}$ and $a_{1}$.

**What I know**: It's enough to find the Laurent expansion of $\dfrac{1}{\cos(2z)}$ because the expansion of $e^{z}$ is clear, but in all examples that I have done before, the range for $ z $ is something like $ \vert z - \alpha \vert < r $. But here, this range is different. Can anyone help me solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $a_{-1}$ is the [Residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)) of $f(z) = \frac{e^{z}}{cos(z)}$ but if $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ with $p,q$ holomorphic function and $z_{0}$ is a simple zero of $q$ such that $p(z_{0}) \ne 0$ Res$(f,z_{0}) = \frac{p(z_{0})}{q'(z_{0})}$

Comment: Thank you, I haven't get my answer yet. Residue at which point?

Comment: Which and how many zeros of $f(z)$ are in $ \left\lbrace \dfrac{\pi}{4} < \vert z \vert < \dfrac{3\pi}{4} \right\rbrace$ ?

Comment: And what about $a_{1}$? You haven't said anything about that.

Comment: I think your answer is incorrect. By Mathematica $a_{-1}=0$. Besides, it's $\cos(2z)$ not $\cos(z)$.